# Open a new Firefox tab without focusing the browser window

Tags: firefox, gnome-3

I know that I can open a tab in Firefox from another program, for example using the following command:

```
firefox -new-tab https://stackoverflow.com/
```

When running this command, however, the Firefox window will get the focus (at least on Fedora 21 with Gnome 3). This is really annoying: My use case is that I browse through the headlines in my feed reader, which is a standalone program, and hit "open in browser" (which executes a configurable command, see above) on every article I'd like to read, before reading even one. This is necessary for example when I want to open tabs while I'm online but read them later while commuting or traveling.

Thus, my question boils down to the following:

*Is there any way I can open a link in Firefox without needing to hit Alt+Tab every time to switch back from Firefox to the program I opened the tab with?*